# Show current date and time with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I'm not a jQuery developer but I want an output like this:

> Saturday, June 9th, 2007, 5:46:21 PM

Please check out this code ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NgHZB/)).

```
<span id="date"></span>

var now = new Date();
dateFormat(now, "dddd, mmmm dS, yyyy, h:MM:ss TT");
 // Saturday, June 9th, 2007, 5:46:21 PM
$('#date').append(now);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Answer (score 6):

Using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/yS4da/)

```
var now = moment().format("dddd, MMMM Do, YYYY, h:mm:ss A");
     // Saturday, June 9th, 2007, 5:46:21 PM
$('#date').append(now);
```

Output:

```
Saturday, January 5th, 2013, 9:01:22 AM
```

But no need to change anything if you would be using the older (2009) [date.format.js](http://stevenlevithan.com/assets/misc/date.format.js) Ian Atkin found for you and you needed to include in the first place:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/LqVmx/)

Output

`Saturday, January 5th, 2013, 9:48:33 AM`

Comment: Should be h:mm:ss, not h:MM:ss.

Comment: Sorry I should have left more info. MM is month, mm is minute. It is showing hour, month, second.

Answer (score 1):

Use this `dateFormat` function, available at [this link](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format). It even has the exact same format that you asked about.

Once you include the function you can run your code **unaltered**!

```
/*
 * Date Format 1.2.3
 * (c) 2007-2009 Steven Levithan <stevenlevithan.com>
 * MIT license
 *
 * Includes enhancements by Scott Trenda <scott.trenda.net>
 * and Kris Kowal <cixar.com/~kris.kowal/>
 *
 * Accepts a date, a mask, or a date and a mask.
 * Returns a formatted version of the given date.
 * The date defaults to the current date/time.
 * The mask defaults to dateFormat.masks.default.
 */

var dateFormat = function () {
    var token = /d{1,4}|m{1,4}|yy(?:yy)?|([HhMsTt])\1?|[LloSZ]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*'/g,
        timezone = /\b(?:[PMCEA][SDP]T|(?:Pacific|Mountain|Central|Eastern|Atlantic) (?:Standard|Daylight|Prevailing) Time|(?:GMT|UTC)(?:[-+]\d{4})?)\b/g,
        timezoneClip = /[^-+\dA-Z]/g,
        pad = function (val, len) {
            val = String(val);
            len = len || 2;
            while (val.length < len) val = "0" + val;
            return val;
        };

    // Regexes and supporting functions are cached through closure
    return function (date, mask, utc) {
        var dF = dateFormat;

        // You can't provide utc if you skip other args (use the "UTC:" mask prefix)
        if (arguments.length == 1 && Object.prototype.toString.call(date) == "[object String]" && !/\d/.test(date)) {
            mask = date;
            date = undefined;
        }

        // Passing date through Date applies Date.parse, if necessary
        date = date ? new Date(date) : new Date;
        if (isNaN(date)) throw SyntaxError("invalid date");

        mask = String(dF.masks[mask] || mask || dF.masks["default"]);

        // Allow setting the utc argument via the mask
        if (mask.slice(0, 4) == "UTC:") {
            mask = mask.slice(4);
            utc = true;
        }

        var _ = utc ? "getUTC" : "get",
            d = date[_ + "Date"](),
            D = date[_ + "Day"](),
            m = date[_ + "Month"](),
            y = date[_ + "FullYear"](),
            H = date[_ + "Hours"](),
            M = date[_ + "Minutes"](),
            s = date[_ + "Seconds"](),
            L = date[_ + "Milliseconds"](),
            o = utc ? 0 : date.getTimezoneOffset(),
            flags = {
                d:    d,
                dd:   pad(d),
                ddd:  dF.i18n.dayNames[D],
                dddd: dF.i18n.dayNames[D + 7],
                m:    m + 1,
                mm:   pad(m + 1),
                mmm:  dF.i18n.monthNames[m],
                mmmm: dF.i18n.monthNames[m + 12],
                yy:   String(y).slice(2),
                yyyy: y,
                h:    H % 12 || 12,
                hh:   pad(H % 12 || 12),
                H:    H,
                HH:   pad(H),
                M:    M,
                MM:   pad(M),
                s:    s,
                ss:   pad(s),
                l:    pad(L, 3),
                L:    pad(L > 99 ? Math.round(L / 10) : L),
                t:    H < 12 ? "a"  : "p",
                tt:   H < 12 ? "am" : "pm",
                T:    H < 12 ? "A"  : "P",
                TT:   H < 12 ? "AM" : "PM",
                Z:    utc ? "UTC" : (String(date).match(timezone) || [""]).pop().replace(timezoneClip, ""),
                o:    (o > 0 ? "-" : "+") + pad(Math.floor(Math.abs(o) / 60) * 100 + Math.abs(o) % 60, 4),
                S:    ["th", "st", "nd", "rd"][d % 10 > 3 ? 0 : (d % 100 - d % 10 != 10) * d % 10]
            };

        return mask.replace(token, function ($0) {
            return $0 in flags ? flags[$0] : $0.slice(1, $0.length - 1);
        });
    };
}();

// Some common format strings
dateFormat.masks = {
    "default":      "ddd mmm dd yyyy HH:MM:ss",
    shortDate:      "m/d/yy",
    mediumDate:     "mmm d, yyyy",
    longDate:       "mmmm d, yyyy",
    fullDate:       "dddd, mmmm d, yyyy",
    shortTime:      "h:MM TT",
    mediumTime:     "h:MM:ss TT",
    longTime:       "h:MM:ss TT Z",
    isoDate:        "yyyy-mm-dd",
    isoTime:        "HH:MM:ss",
    isoDateTime:    "yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:MM:ss",
    isoUtcDateTime: "UTC:yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:MM:ss'Z'"
};

// Internationalization strings
dateFormat.i18n = {
    dayNames: [
        "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat",
        "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
    ],
    monthNames: [
        "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec",
        "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
    ]
};

// For convenience...
Date.prototype.format = function (mask, utc) {
    return dateFormat(this, mask, utc);
};
```

Comment: Well found. I was trying the same but got the wrong code - ended up with moment instead

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

HTML:

```
<span id="date"></span>
```

Javascript:

```
function date (format, timestamp) {
    var that = this,
      jsdate,
      f,
      formatChr = /\\?([a-z])/gi,
      formatChrCb,
      // Keep this here (works, but for code commented-out
      // below for file size reasons)
      //, tal= [],
      _pad = function (n, c) {
        n = n.toString();
        return n.length < c ? _pad('0' + n, c, '0') : n;
      },
      txt_words = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Wednes", "Thurs", "Fri", "Satur", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  formatChrCb = function (t, s) {
    return f[t] ? f[t]() : s;
  };
  f = {
    // Day
    d: function () { // Day of month w/leading 0; 01..31
      return _pad(f.j(), 2);
    },
    D: function () { // Shorthand day name; Mon...Sun
      return f.l().slice(0, 3);
    },
    j: function () { // Day of month; 1..31
      return jsdate.getDate();
    },
    l: function () { // Full day name; Monday...Sunday
      return txt_words[f.w()] + 'day';
    },
    N: function () { // ISO-8601 day of week; 1[Mon]..7[Sun]
      return f.w() || 7;
    },
    S: function () { // Ordinal suffix for day of month; st, nd, rd, th
      var j = f.j();
      if(j < 4 || j > 20){
        return (['st', 'nd', 'rd'])[j % 10 - 1];
      }
      else
      {
        return 'th';
      }
    },
    w: function () { // Day of week; 0[Sun]..6[Sat]
      return jsdate.getDay();
    },
    z: function () { // Day of year; 0..365
      var a = new Date(f.Y(), f.n() - 1, f.j()),
        b = new Date(f.Y(), 0, 1);
      return Math.round((a - b) / 864e5);
    },

    // Week
    W: function () { // ISO-8601 week number
      var a = new Date(f.Y(), f.n() - 1, f.j() - f.N() + 3),
        b = new Date(a.getFullYear(), 0, 4);
      return _pad(1 + Math.round((a - b) / 864e5 / 7), 2);
    },

    // Month
    F: function () { // Full month name; January...December
      return txt_words[6 + f.n()];
    },
    m: function () { // Month w/leading 0; 01...12
      return _pad(f.n(), 2);
    },
    M: function () { // Shorthand month name; Jan...Dec
      return f.F().slice(0, 3);
    },
    n: function () { // Month; 1...12
      return jsdate.getMonth() + 1;
    },
    t: function () { // Days in month; 28...31
      return (new Date(f.Y(), f.n(), 0)).getDate();
    },

    // Year
    L: function () { // Is leap year?; 0 or 1
      var j = f.Y();
      return j % 4 === 0 & j % 100 !== 0 | j % 400 === 0;
    },
    o: function () { // ISO-8601 year
      var n = f.n(),
        W = f.W(),
        Y = f.Y();
      return Y + (n === 12 && W < 9 ? 1 : n === 1 && W > 9 ? -1 : 0);
    },
    Y: function () { // Full year; e.g. 1980...2010
      return jsdate.getFullYear();
    },
    y: function () { // Last two digits of year; 00...99
      return f.Y().toString().slice(-2);
    },

    // Time
    a: function () { // am or pm
      return jsdate.getHours() > 11 ? "pm" : "am";
    },
    A: function () { // AM or PM
      return f.a().toUpperCase();
    },
    B: function () { // Swatch Internet time; 000..999
      var H = jsdate.getUTCHours() * 36e2,
        // Hours
        i = jsdate.getUTCMinutes() * 60,
        // Minutes
        s = jsdate.getUTCSeconds(); // Seconds
      return _pad(Math.floor((H + i + s + 36e2) / 86.4) % 1e3, 3);
    },
    g: function () { // 12-Hours; 1..12
      return f.G() % 12 || 12;
    },
    G: function () { // 24-Hours; 0..23
      return jsdate.getHours();
    },
    h: function () { // 12-Hours w/leading 0; 01..12
      return _pad(f.g(), 2);
    },
    H: function () { // 24-Hours w/leading 0; 00..23
      return _pad(f.G(), 2);
    },
    i: function () { // Minutes w/leading 0; 00..59
      return _pad(jsdate.getMinutes(), 2);
    },
    s: function () { // Seconds w/leading 0; 00..59
      return _pad(jsdate.getSeconds(), 2);
    },
    u: function () { // Microseconds; 000000-999000
      return _pad(jsdate.getMilliseconds() * 1000, 6);
    },

    // Timezone
    e: function () { // Timezone identifier; e.g. Atlantic/Azores, ...
      // The following works, but requires inclusion of the very large
      // timezone_abbreviations_list() function.
/*              return that.date_default_timezone_get();
*/
      throw 'Not supported (see source code of date() for timezone on how to add support)';
    },
    I: function () { // DST observed?; 0 or 1
      // Compares Jan 1 minus Jan 1 UTC to Jul 1 minus Jul 1 UTC.
      // If they are not equal, then DST is observed.
      var a = new Date(f.Y(), 0),
        // Jan 1
        c = Date.UTC(f.Y(), 0),
        // Jan 1 UTC
        b = new Date(f.Y(), 6),
        // Jul 1
        d = Date.UTC(f.Y(), 6); // Jul 1 UTC
      return ((a - c) !== (b - d)) ? 1 : 0;
    },
    O: function () { // Difference to GMT in hour format; e.g. +0200
      var tzo = jsdate.getTimezoneOffset(),
        a = Math.abs(tzo);
      return (tzo > 0 ? "-" : "+") + _pad(Math.floor(a / 60) * 100 + a % 60, 4);
    },
    P: function () { // Difference to GMT w/colon; e.g. +02:00
      var O = f.O();
      return (O.substr(0, 3) + ":" + O.substr(3, 2));
    },
    T: function () { // Timezone abbreviation; e.g. EST, MDT, ...
      // The following works, but requires inclusion of the very
      // large timezone_abbreviations_list() function.
/*              var abbr = '', i = 0, os = 0, default = 0;
      if (!tal.length) {
        tal = that.timezone_abbreviations_list();
      }
      if (that.php_js && that.php_js.default_timezone) {
        default = that.php_js.default_timezone;
        for (abbr in tal) {
          for (i=0; i < tal[abbr].length; i++) {
            if (tal[abbr][i].timezone_id === default) {
              return abbr.toUpperCase();
            }
          }
        }
      }
      for (abbr in tal) {
        for (i = 0; i < tal[abbr].length; i++) {
          os = -jsdate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60;
          if (tal[abbr][i].offset === os) {
            return abbr.toUpperCase();
          }
        }
      }
*/
      return 'UTC';
    },
    Z: function () { // Timezone offset in seconds (-43200...50400)
      return -jsdate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60;
    },

    // Full Date/Time
    c: function () { // ISO-8601 date.
      return 'Y-m-d\\TH:i:sP'.replace(formatChr, formatChrCb);
    },
    r: function () { // RFC 2822
      return 'D, d M Y H:i:s O'.replace(formatChr, formatChrCb);
    },
    U: function () { // Seconds since UNIX epoch
      return jsdate / 1000 | 0;
    }
  };
  this.date = function (format, timestamp) {
    that = this;
    jsdate = (timestamp === undefined ? new Date() : // Not provided
      (timestamp instanceof Date) ? new Date(timestamp) : // JS Date()
      new Date(timestamp * 1000) // UNIX timestamp (auto-convert to int)
    );
    return format.replace(formatChr, formatChrCb);
  };
  return this.date(format, timestamp);
}

$(function(){
    $('#date').text(date('l, F jS, Y, h:i:s A'));
});
```

This can format your date just like PHP's `date` function.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/licson0729/jHHsm/)**

**UPDATE** The function is improved to give correct and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why, but adding an empty character is giving the desired output

Also, I replaced `append` with `html`

[**JS Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NgHZB/11/)

PS : Would love to know from the more experienced guys why there was a need to add a blank character before or after the `now2` variable for the output to be displayed.

Comment: `now2.toString()` would have done the trick to, but I don't think it's what john wanted, because it's not exactly his format.

Comment: It's just a cheesy way to do type conversion. It forces JavaScript to treat it as a string. You can also do `now2.toString()`. Similarly, adding `0` to a stringified integer will force JavaScript to treat it as an integer, or you can use `parseInt()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var now = moment().format("dddd, MMMM Do, YYYY, h:MM:ss A");
     // ___day, month _th, 20__, _:__:__ _M
$('#date').append(now);
```

Format : *Saturday, June 9th, 2007, 5:46:21 PM* .
This code works.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps.

```js
  $(function(){
 var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getDay()
 var y = d.getFullYear();
 var m = d.getMonth();
 
 /* Days */
 var weekday = new Array(7);
    weekday[0] = "Sunday";
    weekday[1] = "Monday";
    weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
    weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
    weekday[4] = "Thursday";
    weekday[5] = "Friday";
    weekday[6] = "Saturday";
 var day = weekday[d.getDay()];
 
 /* Months */
 var month = new Array(); 
    month[0] = "January";
    month[1] = "February";
    month[2] = "March";
    month[3] = "April";
    month[4] = "May";
    month[5] = "June";
    month[6] = "July";
    month[7] = "August";
    month[8] = "September";
    month[9] = "October";
    month[10] = "November";
    month[11] = "December";
 var n = month[d.getMonth()];
 
 var dated = n +" , "+day+" , "+m+" , "+y;
  
    /* 12 hours format */
 var TwentyFourHour = d.getHours();
    var hour = d.getHours();
    if(hour > 12) { hour = hour - 12;}    
    if(hour==0){ hour=12; }
    
 /* AM and PM */
 var min = d.getMinutes();
 var mid = ' PM';
    if (min < 10) { min = "0" + min; }
 if(TwentyFourHour < 12) { mid = 'am'; }  
 
   /* Good Day , Good Morning , Good evening */
    var greeting;
    var time = new Date().getHours();
    if (time < 10) {
        greeting = "Great attitude is like a perfect cup of coffee – don’t start you day without it. Good morning.";
    } else if (time < 20) {
        greeting = "The power of imagination makes us infinite. Good day";
    } else {
        greeting = "Believe in yourself! Have faith in your abilities!. Good evening";
    }
   document.getElementById("dated").innerHTML =dated +","+hour+':'+min + mid;
   document.getElementById("extra").innerHTML =dated +","+hour+':'+min + mid + " " +greeting;
  
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="font-family:sans-serif; font-weight:300" id="dated" ></div> 
 
<div style="font-family:sans-serif; font-weight:300" id="extra" ></div>
```